# Android app crashes when invoking getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My problem is similar to [Android starting application after searching for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758948/android-starting-application-after-searching-for-it)

I call

```
locationHelper.setLocationManager(this);  // pass the appcontext to my helper method
```

from my main Activity's `onCreate()`.
My LocationHelper class looks like this:

```
public class LocationHelper {

  private LocationManager locationManager;
    [...]
    public void setLocationManager(Context context){
      locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    [...]
}
```

When I leave the `setLocationManager()` call out, the app runs fine, if not it crashes and leaves following on the Stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1647    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1663 
    ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 931   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Could someone help me interpret those messages since I haven't found any documentation anywhere on debugging android apps.

Comment: thnx for the cleanup, firefox 4b12 didn't show all that options of the editor...

Comment: Kesssel: That is not a stack trace. Or, perhaps more accurately, it is Eclipse's rendition of the wrong stack trace. Run past the point of the exception and use the DDMS perspective to examine LogCat to find the real exception.

Comment: my problem is, since my call is in the `onCreate()`, that the program crashes right at start. Thus I can't activate the Heap inspector or the thread viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); directly into the onCreate-Method. Does it work there?

Have you requested the permissions in your Manifest.xml to access Locations?

Comment: I've registered ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION; ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION; ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest; passing the LocationManager directly leads into the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Forget all use this simple and good working code and have fun :)

```
LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Don't use

```
context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
```

or

```
 this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
```

Comment: This is wrong, if we're not in an Activity class we need to get a reference to the actual context, in my case the problem was that I was calling the getSystemService on an invalid context reference, now I do getContext().getSystemService